# How to exclude a specific file from being copied using xcopy

Tags: batch-file, xcopy

I'm new to Windows batch files, but I'm writing a `.bat` file that just copies a bunch of files from one place to another maintaining the file directory structure. Using `xcopy` this is simple but I need to exclude some files from being copied. You can use `/exclude` and create a text file full of strings that you want to be excluded, but this doesn't just exclude files with the exact names in the text file, it excludes all files whose filenames contain any of the strings in the text file.

What this means is, if I want to exclude any files named `123.txt` and put this string in my exclusions text file, if there was a file called `1123.txt` anywhere in the source folder or any of its subfolders that would also be excluded.

How can I exclude only files with a specific filename from being copied?

Comment: You should look at `robocopy` there are a ton of switches for that command, maybe some of them will do what you need.

Comment: Not using DOS...just windows batch file commands. Edited question.

Comment: The machine I need to run this on is running XP, apparently robocopy wasn't made standard until windows 7

Comment: Robocopy for xp - http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=17657

Comment: I don't have the option to change anything about the machine, it's a standard setup that's widely distributed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Evening Bill.

Can you add a slash before each file name? That should work

EG

instead of

> 123.txt
>
> blah.txt

use

> \123.txt
>
> \blah.txt

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a temporary folder, `xcopy`ing all of the files into that folder, deleting the ones you *don't* want, then `xcopy`ing those to the final destination. Finally, delete the temporary folder and its contents with `rd xyzzy /q/s`